# Add local repo for existing Xcode 5 Project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode5

I've running through a Xcode 5 tutorial and want to make some significant changes, but want to make this Xcode 5 project into a repository.

I've done some reading and you can add a repository by going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Add Respository -> Enter the repository address:

So what would I input here for a local repository (on my iMac) I'm wanting to work on?

Cheers.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would do this from the command line.

1. Close `Xcode.app`
2. Open `Terminal.app`
3. `$ cd /path/to/project/dir`
4. `$ git init .`
5. Create a `.gitignore` file to ignore some of the Xcode and output files that you don't want tracked (see below).
6. `$ git add .gitignore`
7. `$ git add .`
8. `$ git commit -a -m Initial.`

Sample (but incomplete) `.gitignore` file:

```
build/
*/xcuserdata/
```

And most likely you'll want to add a remote tracking repo, perhaps on github or bitbucket (once a *bare* repo has been created there):

```
$ git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/yourname/yourrepo.git
$ git push -u origin --all
$ git push -u origin --tags
```

When you open the Xcode project next time it will be ready for Source Code use.

Comment: @shashwat Yes, and each one is different. 4. it's the current directory. 6 it marks the file as hidden and 7. it's a full stop.

Comment: Steps 5 and 6 did not work for me. I had to use this instead: $ touch .gitignore

Comment: You will have to do a "git add ." before doing a git commit

Answer (score 5):

Apple's official solution is [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1)
See "Use Git to Manage an Unmanaged Workspace Directory on a Development Mac"

Answer (score 0):

That's only for already existing repos that are stored somewhere outside of your project directory. You can create a new repo by opening the terminal in the top-level folder of your project, and then typing `git init`. Your repo is now created and will automatically be recognized by Xcode.