# how to add existing project including pods to bitbucket using xcode?

Tags: bitbucket, xcode8

hello all as I m newbie to bitbucket,i don't know how to upload the project to bitbucket. I followed this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33280784/8170423 but in my case I'm having 2branch one is of my project and another is of pods.And this is the point i'm stucked can't figure out how to upload my project including pods to bitbucket.Please Help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey it's very simple as well as easy follow the mention steps given in below link
http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2016/02/send-xcode-project-to-bitbucket.html hope it helps you.